# Sprite.rotation Not working in box2d

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, box2d

I have an array of Sprites, that the user is allowed to move that is handled within ccTouchesMoved.

When the user has one of the sprites selected (by touching it) they then have the option to rotate the sprite using the ccTouchesMoved method, until they unselect the rotation feature.

The sprite rotates correctly, however I have another method that creates edges around the sprites, so that they will have the power for collisions and what not.

When this method is called, it is resetting the rotation of all my Sprites setting them back to 0 and I do not know why.

```
 for (CCSprite *sprite in bounceBarriers)
    {
        curBarrier = sprite;
        curBarrier.rotation = 20;
        [self bounceCreator];
    }

//bounceCreator:

b2BodyDef barrierBodyDef;
barrierBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
barrierBodyDef.position.Set(curBarrier
                            .position.x/PTM_RATIO, curBarrier.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
barrierBodyDef.userData = curBarrier; //the userData is set to the current sprite

_body2 = _world->CreateBody(&barrierBodyDef);
barrierBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);

b2Body *barrierBody;
barrierBody = _world->CreateBody(&barrierBodyDef);

b2EdgeShape barrierEdge;
b2FixtureDef barrierShapeDef;
barrierShapeDef.shape = &barrierEdge;
barrierShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
barrierShapeDef.restitution = 1.0f;
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x-70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y+10)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x-70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y-10)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x-70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y-10)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x+70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y-10)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x+70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y-10)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x+70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y+10)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
barrierEdge.Set(b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x+70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y+10)/PTM_RATIO),
                b2Vec2((curBarrier.position.x-70)/PTM_RATIO, (curBarrier.position.y+10)/PTM_RATIO));
barrierBody->CreateFixture(&barrierShapeDef);
```

Comment: also: curBarrier.rotation = 20; is set there for testing. It is being set back to 0, not 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also update b2body's rotation.

```
   body->SetTransform([self toB2Meters: sprite.position], -1*CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(20));
```

Comment: Great start Guru. That prevented the reset of the rotation to 0 (I had to change a few things to get your method to work, but the SetTransform() method was the key. HOWEVER, now the bodyEdge is not being set, i.e the collisions arent being detected.

Thanks for your help so far, maybe you have 1 more final point of wisdom, as this problem has been plauging me for the last day.

Comment: Welcome..Happy coding Sam.